# Merge two ansible variable

Tags: filter, module, ansible

I have cluster command to create stonith device need to convert to ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Create stonith
  shell: pcs stonith create {{ fence_name }} fence_vmware_soap pcmk_host_map="node2.domain.com:TEST_PCS_NODE_2;node1.domain.com:TEST_PCS_NODE_1" ipaddr={{ vcenter_ip }} ssl_insecure=1 login={{ vcenter_username }} passwd={{ vcenter_password }}
```

I have created variables for below vm names:

```yaml
node2_name: node2.domain.com
vm2_name: TEST_PCS_NODE_2
node1_name: node1.domain.com
vm1_name: TEST_PCS_NODE_1
```

But need help in create combine or merge or join filter to get below syntax:
`node2.domain.com:TEST_PCS_NODE_2;node1.domain.com:TEST_PCS_NODE_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no special filters required for this, you can simply have a string with variable interpolation:

`{{ node2_name }}:{{ vm2_name }};{{ node1_name }}:{{ vm1_name }}`

In task:

```yaml
- name: Create stonith
  shell: pcs stonith create {{ fence_name }} fence_vmware_soap pcmk_host_map="{{ node2_name }}:{{ vm2_name }};{{ node1_name }}:{{ vm1_name }}" ipaddr={{ vcenter_ip }} ssl_insecure=1 login={{ vcenter_username }} passwd={{ vcenter_password }}
```